# Firebase query second level with react redux firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux, react-redux-firebase

I have a firebase database who contains all purchase of my users

```
purchase
    userId1
         purchaseId1
         purchaseId2
         purchaseId3
   userId2
         purchaseId1
         purchaseId2
         purchaseId3
```

A purchase object (ex: purchaseId1) contains a price and a specific code

```
{
 price:100,
 code:'2XBE'
}
```

I search a query to find all purchase with the code '3XB1'

I use react-redux-firebase

Thanks

Comment: just hit the url directly /purchase/{auth.user}/purchase1

Comment: But only with the good code in purchase object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change the structure of your database

```
purchase : {
      purchaseId : {
           price:100,
           code:'2XBE'
           userId : 1
      }     
}
```

now you can do this

```
firebase.database().ref().child("purchase")
                   .orderByChild("code").equalsTo("3XB1")
                   .on( snap => console.log(snap.val() )
```

Comment: You know how to do this kind of request with react-redux-firebase ?

Comment: sorry I didn't used react-redux-firebase